# NullPointerException in SVM classifier

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, machine-learning

I am writing code for SVM classifier in Java but getting NullPointerException. The code is as follows:

```
Mat labelsMat = new Mat(10,1, CvType.CV_32FC1);
Mat training_data_Mat = new Mat(10, 6, CvType.CV_32FC1);
labelsMat.put(0, 0, labels); 

for (int i =0; i < 10;i++) {
    training_data_Mat.put(i,0, training_data[i]);
}

CvSVM svm = new CvSVM();
CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
params.set_svm_type(CvSVM.C_SVC);
params.set_kernel_type(CvSVM.RBF);
params.set_term_crit(new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.MAX_ITER,100,1e-6));
svm.train(training_data_Mat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

Here training_data_Mat is a (10,6) matrix of datatype double[][]while labelsMat is a (1,10) vector of type double[].

I am getting stuck at last line in code with NullPointerException.
Can somebody please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: put a breakpoint on the line and inspect all the variables, you'll find one is null. Then work backwards from there to find out why.

Comment: Provide more details about exception.
Also maybe problem in varIdx and sampleIdx parameters, try to set them to null instead of Mat()

Comment: Or set them to vectors of indexes of features and objects used for training.

Comment: @Olologin::   07-29 17:53:55.147: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-29 17:53:55.147: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-29 17:53:55.147: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

Comment: 07-29 17:53:55.147: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-29 17:53:55.147: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-29 17:53:55.147: E/AndroidRuntime(21223): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 17:53:55.147: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):  at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.train

Comment: @Diego Martinoia:: Here after converting the double values into 32bit floating point value (lines 3-10 in above code block), I'm getting different values than those of initial training_data. Most of them are zero. I'm using following code for accessing these values::                                           for(int m=0; m<10; m++)
         {
          for(int n=0; n<6; n++)
          {
           Log.d("Value of Training_data_Mat is:: "," "+training_data_Mat.get(m, n)[0]);
          }
         }        Is anything wrong in this??

Comment: I doubt that's the issue. Wrong indices would raise IndexOutOfBound exceptions, not NPE's (unless the matrices are of boxed types [i.e. Capital Integer, Long etc] which may be null). I suggest you manually inspect your library, in particular theline (unfortuntately, you didn't paste the line no.) "E/AndroidRuntime(21223): at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.train " Looking at the code there you'll probably be able to tell what triggers the NPE and walk backwards.

Comment: @Diego Martinoia:: Sorry for late reply. Error is coming at line no 270. I checked but not getting what's the problem(Why this NPE is coming. In fact no argument in svm.train is null in my code).Please suggest something.                                         08-04 16:17:53.000: E/AndroidRuntime(6019):  at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.train(CvSVM.java:270)

Comment: @Olologin:: When I'm assigning null pointers to varIdx and sampleIdx then also I'm getting NPE. Now what should I do? Please help.

Comment: Sorry mate, my best suggestion at this point would be to put a breakpoint before the call and start going step by step (step in) into the library.

Comment: @Diego Martinoia:: ok....Thank you :)